# "Considero/ritengo sbagliato che"

Tags: grammar

> Considero/ritengo giusto che aiuti chi sta in difficoltà. 
>   Considero/ritengo giusto aiutare chi sta in difficoltà.

Grammaticalmente sono frasi corrette, ne sono sicuro, eppure in questa frase (a parte i soliti aggettivi come giusto o sbagliato) ogni altro aggettivo mi suona male male, tipo: "ritengo bello trascorrere/che tu trascorra le vacanze qui."
Grammaticalmente quest'ultima mi sembra corretta, eppure non suona.
È solo una mia impressione?

Comment: Ritengo poco corretto scrivere "apparte" anziché "a parte".

Comment: @DaG: È vero! Ho sbagliato, ma capita. Posso avere una risposta alla mia domanda?

Comment: La frase di @DaG non è un esempio di quello che stai chiedendo nella domanda?

Comment: @Charo: volevo sapere se fosse possibile e non fosse cacofonico usare altri aggettivi che non fossero corretto o sbagliato. Ho fatto due frasi in cui ho usato l'aggettivo bello, che mi risultava cacofonico in quell frase, seppur corretto.

Answer (score 2):

Ritengo così normale usare “ritenere” o “considerare” con qualsiasi aggettivo che non so bene come formulare una risposta che sia convincente per l'OP, né mi è chiaro dove sarebbe la cacofonia. Considero utile aggiungere forse qualche esempio d'autore, ma non sono facilissimi da trovare, anche perché un tempo questi due verbi non venivano usati in questo senso. Per esempio, in Dante “ritenere” ha sensi più affini a “trattenere, mantenere” o “ricordare”, mentre “considerare” sta per “riflettere, meditare” o, transitivamente, “porre mente a” (“Considerate la vostra semenza...”).

In Google Books si trova qualche esempio come

> ritengo bello poter rendere pubbliche le interviste raccolte
>
> ritengo bello e doveroso che sia reso omaggio all'uomo
>
> Considero bello che si vogliano offrire all'uomo sempre migliori sussidi

e così via. Forse il motivo per cui non abbondano esempi con “bello” è che spesso si evita di abusare di questo aggettivo (soprattutto in un senso generico come questo, piuttosto che nello specifico senso estetico) a favore di aggettivi più precisi: opportuno, corretto, appropriato, piacevole e così via.

Comunque non bisogna farsi intimidire: la struttura combinatoria della grammatica dell'italiano rende possibili e corrette, e magari anche interessanti, innumerevoli combinazioni di parole mai pronunciate o scritte prima.

Comment: Grazie mille per la risposta molto completa. In merito alla questione vorrei portare come esempio queste due frasi " ritengo/Considero una cosa positiva agire così" e " ritengo/considero una cosa positiva  che tu faccia questa scelta".  Sono anche queste GRAMMATICALMENTE  corrette e usate?  Grazie mille.

Comment: Direi proprio di sì.